# Logging time as a student

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, student-pilot

Lets say I am a student with no student certificate but I have a good friend who has flown for years on an airbus and I want him to teach me how to fly. Can I log flight time being that I don't have a student Certificate?

Answer (score 8):

You can log anything you want in your own logbook. But in order for that flight time to count towards a certificate, rating, flight review or currency it must be logged in accordance with 14 CFR Part 61.51.

[14 CFR Part 61.51(h)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61/section-61.51#p-61.51(h)) allows the logging of training time when receiving training from an [authorized instructor](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61#p-61.1(b)(Authorized%20instructor)) .  Having a student pilot certificate is **not** required unless you are flying solo.

If your friend the Airbus pilot is not a Certificated Flight Instructor (CFI) then the training time would not count towards a certificate, rating, flight review or currency. It is still legal for him to teach you, but the hours will not count, and he cannot give endorsements.

Comment: Many pilots flying an Airbus have an ATP rating.  An ATP is allowed to give instruction in certain specific cases (see 14 CFR Part 61.167)  https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-G/section-61.167   And, many ATPs are also CFIs, so it depends.

Comment: @Adam The type of instruction that an ATP can give would only apply to someone being instructed in "air transportation service." For example, under an FAR Part 121 approved training program the instruction can be (and mostly, but not always, is in my experience) given by the holder of an ATP certificate who does not also hold a CFI certificate. Also, look at 61.167 (a)(2)(iii). The OP's question would rule out an ATP-only giving instruction to a student pilot (or anyone else that is not being instructed in "air transportation service.")

Comment: The ATP only "instructor" can only instruct using an approved training program under Part 121, 135, etc.  I do not know of any training programs under those parts that will allow a student pilot to receive instruction.  Most prerequisites for those training programs require at least a commercial pilot certificate.